# how to change current application with workspace?

Tags: workspaces, application-switcher, workspace-switcher

I am using 2 workspaces 1 for chrome and another for vscode. whenever I switch between workspace for vscode to the chrome it switches the application but when I come back to vscode I need to click every time before writing the code. **I want to continue the application where I left**. Is any solution? same with many other applications currently using ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate this but am not getting the same results.

I have three Gnome workspaces, Chrome on the top one, VS Code in the middle one, and an empty bottom one.  I can type in VS Code, then navigate to the upper workspace (using either the [Win] + [Tab] then click on Chrome app, or the [Win] + [PgUp].    I can then browse in Chrome (including typing in address bar, forms, etc.)  then return to the VS Code (again, using either [Win] + [Tab] and choosing the VS Code, or [Win] + [PgDn].    The cursor is blinking right where it was when I navigated away, and the next character I hit on the keyboard appends at the point where the blinking cursor was.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 (with Gnome, and thus, Gnome workspaces).

If you are still experiencing this, could you describe with a little more specificity as to how you are navigating and what steps might help someone recreate the issue?   Also, have you installed any Gnome workspace extensions or anything that might be messing with things?

Here's a post that has a section on Keyboard Shortcuts that describes the various ways to switch between workspaces:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-work-with-workspaces-gnome

There's more than one method ... e.g., ([Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Up] or [Down]) so if the problem is that you are using some keystroke combination that VS Code is intercepting, try a different method to see if that is a workaround, perhaps.